# Pegar todas as divs com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho varias divs em meu site, onde nelas contem a seguinte classe "code$numb" onde $numb é um numero aleatorio, como faco para capturar todas as divs com o code independentemente do $numb?

Comment: Seria mais eficiente adicionar uma outra classe fixa para agrupar todas, por exemplo: `code code$numb`. Isso é muito comum em nuvem de tags.

Comment: Isso, mas como faria para captar todas?

Comment: Assim: `$('.code')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como [o utluiz referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23852/pegar-todas-as-divs-com-jquery#comment44047_23852) neste caso pode ser mais prático criar uma classe para agrupar esses elementos e guardar esse `$numb` de outra maneira (`data-` field por exemplo).

Mas para responder à sua pergunta sobre como capturar todos os elementos com code, independente do `$numb`, pode usar assim:

```
$('div[class^="code"]');
```

onde `^=` significa começando em...

Pode **[ler mais sobre este selector aqui](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**, mas o que diz na descrição é:

> *Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.*
>
> Escolhe os elementos que têm um atributo específico começando exactamente com a string indicada

### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/4P3Ut/

Comment: sou leigo em jquery, seria assim para captar todas as divs?

Comment: @ViniciusEduardo, coloquei um exemplo. Esse seletor encontra todas as que têm classe começada por "code"

Comment: Gostei do codigo, simples.. Mas como executar funcoes com ele?

Comment: @ViniciusEduardo, como no jsFiddle que coloquei, um exemplo onde substitui somente os elementos escolhidos e lhes troca o conteúdo `$('div[class^="code"]').text('encontrou!');`

Comment: Sim, mas eu quero enviar uma requisição com Ajax a cada elemento..

Comment: @ViniciusEduardo, ok. E o que quer fazer? carregar esse elemento com conteudo do ajax?

Comment: Sim! enviar uma requisicao ajax e colocala no lugar..

Comment: Hmmmm... vi agora que desmarcou a resposta como aceite. Acho que respondí ao que perguntou. Não perguntou nada sobre Ajax na pergunta e não percebo porque a desmarcou... `:/` Em relação a AJAX dê uma olhada no fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3QUr9/ Se não perceber faça nova pergunta.

Comment: Hey, desculpe.. Por esse ponto voce esta certo, porem nao queria gastar tempo com mais uma pergunta.. Muito obrigado qualquer coisa eu volto :3

Comment: @Sergio é o cara! Esse manja em javascript/jquery!

Comment: Só por curiosidade, caso a necessidade fosse de terminar com `"code"` ficaria: `$('div[class$="code"]')`